# How do I use omnipay to check if it's a pending payment or not

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, omnipay

I'm using Omnipay 2.1 and CodeIgniter 2.1.4 to receive Paypal payments.

I use this line to complete the purchase and check if the payment was sent:

```
$bool = $gateway->completePurchase(array('amount' => $total, 'currency' => 'EUR'))
                ->send()
                ->isSuccessful();
```

But I noticed that the method `isSuccessful()` will also return `true` if the payment is on pending.

How can I use omnipay to check if it's a pending payment or not?

Comment: What does `print_r($response->getData())` return?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BLK6Hqf6 So I guess I have to check that `PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS` is equal to `Completed`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your raw response data, the important lines are:

```
[ACK] => Success
[PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS] => Pending
[PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON] => multicurrency
```

So the payment was processed successfully, but is in a `Pending` state. Omnipay doesn't explicitly check for this, but I'm not sure that would be sensible anyway. From the customer's point of view, the payment was successful, and money has left their account.

Looking at the [PayPal API documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/IT/it_IT/files/developer/PP_NVPAPI_DeveloperGuide.pdf) for `PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON`:

> multi-currency – You do not have a balance in the currency sent, and you do not have your Payment Receiving Preferences set to automatically convert and accept this payment. You must manually accept or deny this payment.

So basically the payment was successful, the only reason it is pending is that you are charging customers in a currency (EUR) that you haven't explicitly enabled in your PayPal account.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you shouldn't be chaining `isSuccessful()` fn. Try just `send()` then checking the response from gateway:

```
$response = $gateway->purchase(['amount' => '10.00', 'currency' => 'USD')->send();

if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
    // payment was successful: update database
    print_r($response);
} else {
    // debug etc;
    print_r($response);
}
```

Otherwise you might be getting a `bool` for `send()` etc;

Comment: Thanks, but it sill gives me `True`, even if `$response ` contains `pending`. Maybe I can't do that with Omnipay and I have to check it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of `OmniPay` have an `isPending` method in the `Response` class that you can use to check if a payment is pending.

If you see the possible [reasons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) for a payment status being pending, some of these may lead to an unsuccessful payment.

E.g.

- paymentreview
- regulatory_review
- echeck.

I would suggest its not a good idea to ship or confirm an order before checking this would not rely on the response `isSuccessful` method returning `true` by itself.